# Access function in external js file from button in webapp

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, azure-iot-hub-device-management

I have a file dmreboot_service.js in my /js folder. When I run this file using node /js/dmreboot_service.js it successfully invokes a direct method in Azure.

I need to be able to execute this function or file on a button click from my web app.

I tried loading the script into the head of my html using :

```
<script src="js/dmreboot_service.js"></script>
```

I put an alert in the external file. 
If I put this alert at the top of the file it works, but at
the bottom it fails, so the contents of the file are not loading.

The content of dmreboot_service.js is :

```js
'use strict';

var Registry = require('azure-iothub').Registry;
var Client = require('azure-iothub').Client;


var connectionString ="HostName=XxxxxxxX.azure-devices.net;SharedAccessKeyName=service;SharedAccessKey=XxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxX=";
var registry = Registry.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var client = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var deviceToReboot = 'Runner';

var startRebootDevice = function (twin) {

  var methodName = "reboot";

  var methodParams = {
      methodName: methodName,
      payload: null,
      timeoutInSeconds: 30
  };

  client.invokeDeviceMethod(deviceToReboot, methodParams, function(err, result) {
      if (err) {
          console.error("Direct method error: "+err.message);
      } else {
          console.log("Successfully invoked the device to reboot.");  
      }
  });
};

var queryTwinLastReboot = function() {

  registry.getTwin(deviceToReboot, function(err, twin){

      if (twin.properties.reported.iothubDM != null)
      {
          if (err) {
              console.error('Could not query twins: ' + err.varructor.name + ': ' + err.message);
          } else {
              var lastRebootTime = twin.properties.reported.iothubDM.reboot.lastReboot;
              console.log('Last reboot time: ' + JSON.stringify(lastRebootTime, null, 2));
          }
      } else 
          console.log('Waiting for device to report last reboot time.');
  });
};

startRebootDevice();
setInterval(queryTwinLastReboot, 2000);

alert('dmreboot included!');
```

I have also tried creating a function in the head of my html that includes the entire contents of dmreboot_service.js, but although the function is called successfully the code does not execute.

This is the last part of a project that I need to get working. I'm fairly new to this, and this is driving me nuts!! Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: Update : I've tracked the problem down to the two lines of code that use Require. Require is not supported in the browser. Will look into browserify or requirejs which apparently enable this.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle click in HTML with javascript like so;

```js
const doSomething = document.querySelector('.whateverclassnameyouchoose').addEventListener('click',onClick);

function onClick(e){
what ever you want the function to do
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi, Many thanks for your response, but I think you may have misunderstood my question. I only have a problem running this particular function from button click This is because the code in the file fails to be included in page head when I use <script src="js/dmreboot_service.js"></script>. The code also fails to execute If I put it in a function in my html, even though the function is called successfully on button click. Many thanks for your help